# Set a global environment variable in Linux that sticks when going root

Tags: linux, bash

When I SSH into a Linux box, I want to have the `/etc/profile` file save the results of the `whoami` command to a global environment variable.

If I were to go root with the command `sudo su -`, I do not want that command to run again when going root. I want it to use the result of `whoami` with my regular username from before I went root, and need to access that variable as the root user even though it will run the `/etc/profile` file again when I go root.

What can I do to only run that command once in the `/etc/profile` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preserving environment variables past a login shell requires the **-m** switch. Preserving environment variables past sudo requires a change to **env_keep** in */etc/sudoers*. Even then, doing this is iffy.

Fortunately, there are other ways to go about this. For example, your tty is owned by the user you initially logged in as. So adding this to the end of /etc/profile:

```
TTY=$(tty)
if [ -n "$TTY" ]; then
    WHOAMI=`ls -al $TTY | awk '{print $3}'`
fi
```

You'll set the WHOAMI variable to the owner of the tty, if there is one, past both sudo and non-sudo su to root:

```
[corman@localhost ~]$ sudo su -
Password:
[root@localhost ~]# echo $WHOAMI
corman
[root@localhost ~]# logout
[corman@localhost ~]$ su -
Password:
[root@localhost ~]# echo $WHOAMI
corman
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: A bit cleaner to write `WHOAMI=$(stat --format="%U" "$TTY")`

Answer (score 3):

You may also use `logname` instead of `whoami`!

Comment: +1. whoami gets confused when sudo elevations are in place, and some scripts really need `logname` to just know who invoked the script, like when changing broken file ownership back to the calling user... rather than inadvertently changing them to "root".